# C++ Trouble with Understanding BFS to find Shortest Path

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

I have a simple graph and my assignment is to find the shortest path between two nodes. I've done my best to read through the BFS pseudocode and examples but it's just not clicking.

My nodes are stored in an adjacency list, (at the moment I'm not concerned with edge weights)
Here's a visual of the data: The first column is the vector element, the row to it's immediate left is another vector. The vector element number represents the number of the corresponding node.

```
=====================================
0  |  (1, 100), (3, 50), (7, 100)
1  |  (0, 100), (4, 50), (5, 10) 
2  |  (3, 1000), (4, 200), (6, 1000) 
3  |  (0, 50), (2, 1000) 
4  |  (1, 50), (2, 200), (6, 100) 
5  |  (1, 10), (6, 50), (7, 2000) 
6  |  (2, 1000), (4, 100), (5, 50) 
7  |  (0, 100), (5, 2000)
```

I'm trying to implement a BFS via the pseudocode I found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode) but I'm not getting it. My adjancency list is stored in a vector: `vector<vector <vertex> > adjList;` `vertex` is a struct of two `int`'s 1)`node` and 2)`weight` (again I'm not really concerned with weights right now but I'm leaving this struct setup this way to modify later)

My implementation is pretty basic:

```
vector<vector <vertex> > adjList;      // the vector adjacency list

// the start and end vertices are passed into the function
int startV;     //num of start node
int endV;       //num of destination node

bool visited = false, done = false;    //control         

vector<int> marked, path;              // holds visited and final path

Queue<int> Q;                          // Q for BFS
Q.push(startV);                        // enqueue BFS

while (!Q.empty() && !done) {

    int t = Q.front(); Q.pop();        // mark and pop(back)
    marked.push_back(t);               // push back start node onto marked

    if (t == endV)                     // if t is our destination
        done = true;                   // done, get out of here

    size_t adjE = adjList[t].size();   // degree of this node

    for (int i = 0; i < adjE; i++) {

        int u = adjList[t][i].node;    // visit each adjacent node

        for (int j = 0; j < marked.size(); j++) {

           if (marked[j] == u)         // test if node has been marked
               visited = true;  
           }
                                       // check if this node has
           if (!visited) {             // already been visited
              marked.push_back(u);     // if not enqueue
              Q.push(u);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I know there has to be something wrong with my implementation. I'm just not seeing what is.

**Update:**
I solved this by using a multimap approach. A detailed explanation is here: [Traverse MultiMap to Find Path from a Given Value to a Given Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15304951/938865)

Comment: you don't put `visited` back to `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic about finding `visited` nodes is incorrect. Try

```
...
int u = adjList[t][i].node;

visited = false;
for (int j = 0; j < marked.size(); j++) {
    // std::find() does essentially all this for you. Check it out.
    if (marked[j] == u) {
        visited = true;
    }
}

if (!visited) {
    marked.push_back(u);
    Q.push(u);
}
```

Comment: it's not building the shortest path. It's revisiting nodes a couple times now. Just so I can be sure. The shortest path will be in marked? Or in queue? Right now I'm printing out the contents of marked but I don't think that's right. I don't know how to keep track of the path as it's discovered by the algorithm

Comment: Neither, you will have to find a way to remember that if `u` is being added to `marked` that `t` put it there. You can use a `std::map<int, int>` to do this.

Comment: So keep a key=>value for each path of each adjacent node. Then just return the shortest one?